# DateTime gives different results for same negative Date

Tags: php, date, datetime, negative-number

I have trouble with the following issue.

Environment: PHP 7.0.8
Code example:

```
$timestamp = -122615337600;

$dt1 = new \DateTime();
$dt1->setTimestamp($timestamp);
$dateStr = $dt1->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

echo 'DateTime1: ' . $dateStr . '<br>';

$dt2 = new \DateTime($dateStr);
$dateStr = $dt2->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

echo 'DateTime2: ' . $dateStr . '<br>';
```

I expect, that the output is equal. But I got:

```
DateTime1: -1916-06-22 00:00:00
DateTime2: -1916-06-21 00:00:00
```

Can someone tell me why is this and how can I fix it?
At first sight I would say, thats a PHP bug?

Comment: Or the short version:

`code`$dt = new \DateTime('-1916-06-22 00:00:00');
echo $dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');`code`

Gives: -1916-06-21 00:00:00

Comment: It does look like a bug, it looks like 5.5.7 was the last version it worked correctly in.

Comment: https://3v4l.org/#version=5.5.7

Comment: I added code to output the time zone (but not in the string that is parsed to produce $dt2). Both time zones were UTC, so that might not be the problem. Might be interesting to specify the time zone when creating $dt2.

Comment: My global timezone was set to UTC.

I created an issue: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=73294